# Simple update command causes SqlException Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlexception

I have an application which converts a mssql-db (source) to another mssql-db (target). For every table in my source i basically get all rows and make an insert for every row to my target. I run a simple query which updates the source-row to store the target-table and target-id of the records which get inserted to the target-db:

```
var commandText = $"UPDATE SOURCE_TABLE SET SOURCE_TABLE.TARGET_ID = '{target_id}', SOURCE_TABLE.TARGET_TBL = '{target_table}' WHERE SOURCE_TABLE.ID = '{id}'";

base.Source.ExecuteNonQuery(commandText);
```

This runs perfectly fine until i try to update the source-row of a specific table. I get an `SqlException Execution Timeout Expired`.

I have checked the variables target_id, target_table and id they are all filled with valid values. I have disabled all triggers and the id-field is primary key.

When i run this command via management-studio, there is not problem. Doesnt even take a second to process.

---

I have used the activity-monitor from management-studio to monitor when the sql runs. The databases with the red box are the target-db.
[image: activity-monitor]
Every single peak in the second diagramm ("Wartende Tasks" = "waiting tasks"). Stands for one time the query has been tried to execute.

---

This is how the command is executed:

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText)
{
    using (var connection = this.CreateConnection()) // new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = commandText;

            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use string concatenation to build queries. Use SQL Parameters.

Comment: I do, this was just to simplify my question.

Comment: Sounds like you're running into a lock situation - what happens when you monitor SQL when it runs

Comment: OK. I'd just keep the params and abbreviate the example by replacing the param-setting part with for example "// parameter setting left out for brevity" or something. Otherwise you will always trigger that "use params" reflex ;)

Comment: did u try setting a commandtimeout  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: @skyuppercut yes i did, but it makes no difference. Also the query runs in under a second on management-studio so the timeout is not the problem i think.

Comment: @bugfinder what do you mean by 'monitor SQL'? Is there a specific tool in the management-studio which i can use?

Comment: sms - sql management studio....

Comment: i used the activity monitor and made a screenshot. Added this to my question. Hope this is what you expected. (Sorry im a newbe to management-studio)

Comment: Can you please show the rest of your code associated to the SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects?

Comment: I have added the body of the ExecuteNonQuery-Method.

Comment: The process which fires the update on the source (56) seems to be locked by the process which selects the data from the source (53). But why does this only appear on this specific table? I do it the same way on the other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, the process which makes the update on the source is blocked by the process which makes select on the source. I had to wrap these into an transaction to use the `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted`. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to add a begin transaction before the query then a commit transaction after the query?  I would try this for both the insert on the source and the update on the target.